# Does Filipino passport holder need Transit Visa in Istanbul for a layover?

Tags: transit-visas, layovers, filipino-citizens, turkish-airlines

I'm a Filipino passport holder. And I'm planning to go to Bogota, Colombia from Vietnam with a layover in Istanbul for 21 hours. Question is do I need transit visa in Istanbul?

Answer (score 1):

No, according to Timatic, the system used by airlines, you do not need a transit visa for Turkey.

To enter Colombia you must have a machine readable passport that is valid for the intended period of stay, and proof of accommodation.

Source: https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external.php?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b

Comment: So, I don't need any Visa for a layover in Istanbul. By the way, I'll be flying with Turkish Airlines from Vietnam to Bogota, Colombia. Another question, do my checked in luggage follows through my final destination? Or do I need to pick it up in Istanbul and then check it in again? Thank you for answering!